# broadleaf mail sender class using spring framework

Tags: spring, jakarta-mail, broadleaf-commerce

what does this mean in java...i saw something new i havn't seen anything like this before...this code sends a mail using spring framework javamailsender class

```
 public MimeMessagePreparator buildMimeMessagePreparator(final HashMap<String,Object> props) {
     MimeMessagePreparator preparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
         public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
             EmailTarget emailUser = (EmailTarget) props.get(EmailPropertyType.USER.getType());
             EmailInfo info = (EmailInfo) props.get(EmailPropertyType.INFO.getType());
             MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, (info.getAttachments() != null && info.getAttachments().size() > 0));
             message.setTo(emailUser.getEmailAddress());
             message.setFrom(info.getFromAddress());
             message.setSubject(info.getSubject());
             if (emailUser.getBCCAddresses() != null && emailUser.getBCCAddresses().length > 0) {
                 message.setBcc(emailUser.getBCCAddresses());
             }
             if (emailUser.getCCAddresses() != null && emailUser.getCCAddresses().length > 0) {
                 message.setCc(emailUser.getCCAddresses());
             }
             String messageBody = info.getMessageBody();
             if (messageBody == null) {                  
                 messageBody = buildMessageBody(info, props);
             }
             message.setText(messageBody, true);
             for (Attachment attachment : info.getAttachments()) {
                 ByteArrayDataSource dataSource = new ByteArrayDataSource(attachment.getData(), attachment.getMimeType());
                 message.addAttachment(attachment.getFilename(), dataSource);
             }
         }
     };  // why there is a semicolon here
     return preparator;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're confused about the semicolon, the code is creating an anonymous inner class that's a subclass of MimeMessagePreparator.  The semicolon is the end of the assignment to the preparator variable.